# How to display currency symbols in MySQL from hexadecimal value?

Tags: mysql, hex, currency

We have a list of Hex values for currency symbols, but couldn't find a way to convert them to the actual symbols in MySQL utf8.

In Oracle we use the UNISTR function:

> select unistr('\20AC'), unistr('\FDFC') from dual;
>
> €, ﷼

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CONVERT('\20AC' USING utf8)

might do the trick.

example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(x'c3a9' USING utf8)
```

will result in a "é"

regards

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT(UNHEX('20ACFDFC') USING ucs2);
+---------------------------------------+
| CONVERT(UNHEX('20ACFDFC') USING ucs2) |
+---------------------------------------+
| €﷼                                    |
+---------------------------------------+
```